# C code- Not enough free memory to read data from txt file into a 1D dynamic array for debug mode

Tags: c, memory, malloc, scanf

I wrote a C code to fscanf a .txt file into a 1D dynamic array. The data in txt file is written in a single column with 108x108x108 integers. However, it says "Not enough storage is available to process this command" when I was trying to debug. If I use the Batch Build to build both release and debug, only the Release mode can successfully load the data into the dynamic array. On the other hand, it shows "There is not enough free memory to run this program. Exit one or more programs, and then try again" when I was trying to click the debug mode .exe. By the way, my computer has 16 GB Ram, so it shouldn't overflow the memory. Anyone can take a look at my code and help me with this problem? I would really appreciate your answers.

```
#define IMMX        108
#define IMMY        108
#define IMMZ        108

int *one;
int Max = IMMX*IMMY*IMMZ;

void input_var(void); // Input 
void output_fields(void); // Output 

void main(int argc,char *argv[])
{
 input_var();

 output_fields();

 free(one);
 one = NULL;

}

void input_var(void)
{
 FILE *rf = fopen("108x108x108.txt","r"); //108*108**108 integers in a single column is 108x108x108.txt file

 one = (int *)malloc(sizeof(int)*Max);
 for(int i=0;i<Max;i++)
    {
     one[i] = 0;
    }

    if (rf == NULL){
        printf("Unable to open file\n");
        } else {
        for (int i=0;i<Max; i++)
         {
           fscanf(rf,"%i",&one[i]);
         }
        fclose(rf);
        }
     }

void output_fields(void)
{
    FILE *file1 = fopen("one", "w");
    for(int i=0;i<Max;i=i++)
       {
         fprintf(file1,"%i",one[i]);
         fprintf(file1,"\n");
       }
    fclose(file1);
 }
```

Comment: Yes, anything wrong with the file name?

Comment: No no ,just clearing . And in function `output_fields` you open a file without extension . You are aware of that right ?

Comment: Yes, it is OK without file extension. It will generate a file named "one", maybe it is confusing with one[i]. You can change the file to any name.

Comment: You're trying to allocate roughly 5MB of memory -- that should work fine on any recent version of Windows (which it sounds like you're using).  Just to be sure, though, verify that your IDE is not set to produce a 16-bit program.  Other corrections to your program (these are all bugs, but they may not be directly responsible for your problem): add `#include <stdlib.h>` and `#include <stdio.h>` at the top; change the type of `Max` (and `i`) to `size_t`; remove the `(int *)` cast of the value returned by `malloc`.

Comment: (cont'd) ... if `fopen` fails, call `perror("108x108x108.txt")` or `fprintf(stderr, "error message: %s: %s\n", "108x108x108.txt", strerror(errno))` rather than just `printf("error message without the offending filename or errno")`; check whether `fopen` failed *immediately* afterward, not with a `malloc` operation in between; if `fopen` fails, do not execute `output_fields`; check whether the `fopen` *inside* `output_fields` failed too; check whether `malloc` failed too.

Comment: the posted code, even with the appropriate #include statements, cause the compiler (gcc) to rais several warnings/  Strongly suggest enabling all warnings when compiling then fix those warnings.  (for gcc, use at a minimum: `-Wall -Wextra -pedantic`)

Comment: please indent code consistently, indent enough that a variable width font will still show the indentation.   Never indent using tabs as each wordprocessor/editor has the tab width/tab stops set differently  Suggest: indent 4 spaces after every opening brace '{'.  un-indent before every closing brace '}'.  for readability, separate code blocks by a blank line.

Comment: if the code will not be doing anything with the data, then simply open both the input and output files in main() followed by a simple read/write loop.  Then no malloc() call is needed.

Answer (score 0):

I did not create the file of integers,

However, I did fix all the 'oops' items in the posted code including adding the needed error checking, the declaration of the main() function, etc

The following code compiles cleanly and should work correctly

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h> // exit(), EXIT_FAILURE
#include <string.h> // memset()

#define IMMX        (108) // when #define'ing numerics, always wrap in parens
#define IMMY        (108)
#define IMMZ        (108)

int *one;
int Max = IMMX*IMMY*IMMZ;

// prototypes
void input_var(void); // Input
void output_fields(void); // Output

int main( void )
{
    input_var();

    output_fields();

    free(one);
    one = NULL;

    return 0; // added as part of correction to main() declaration
} // end function: main

void input_var(void)
{
    FILE *rf = NULL;
    if( NULL == (rf = fopen("108x108x108.txt","r") ) ) //108*108**108 integers in a single column is 108x108x108.txt file
    { // then fopen failed
        perror( "fopen for 108x108x108.txt for input failed");
        exit( EXIT_FAILURE );
    }

    // implied else, fopen successful

    one = malloc(sizeof(int)*Max);
    if( NULL == one )
    { // then, malloc failed
        perror( "malloc for 108*108*108 ints failed");
        fclose( rf ); // cleanup
        exit( EXIT_FAILURE );
    }

    // implied else, malloc successful

    memset( one, 0x00, Max); // initialize the array of ints

    for (int i=0;i<Max; i++) // note: 'i++', not 'i=i++'
    {
        if( 1 != fscanf(rf,"%i",&one[i]) )
        { // then fscanf failed
            perror( "fscanf failed");
            fclose( rf ); // cleanup
            free( one );  // cleanup
            exit( EXIT_FAILURE );
        }

        // implied else, fscanf successful
    } // end for
    fclose(rf);
} // end function: input_var


void output_fields(void)
{
    FILE *file1 = NULL;
    if( NULL == (file1 = fopen("one", "w") ) )
    { // then fopen failed
        perror( "fopen for output file failed");
        free( one ); // cleanup
        exit( EXIT_FAILURE );
    }

    // implied else, fopen successful

    for(int i=0; i<Max; i++)
    {
        fprintf(file1,"%i\n",one[i]);
    }
    fclose(file1);
} // end function: output_fields
```